# How to convert asset to string in a contract?

Tags: smart-contract, c++

How to convert asset to string in a contract?

```
asset my_asset = asset(10000, S(4, EOS));
string my_asset_string = ??? //How to convert my_asset to a string "1.0000 EOS"?
```

Comment: What is the use case? It just eats your cpu...

Answer (score 3):

Actually asset is a struct variable like this:

```
   struct asset {
      /**
       * The amount of the asset
       *
       * @brief The amount of the asset
       */
      int64_t      amount;

      /**
       * The symbol name of the asset
       *
       * @brief The symbol name of the asset
       */
      symbol_type  symbol;
      ...
      ...
}
```

we can find the convert from asset to string in the file **./libraries/chain/asset.cpp** line 23 like this

```
string asset::to_string()const {
   string sign = amount < 0 ? "-" : "";
   int64_t abs_amount = std::abs(amount);
   string result = fc::to_string( static_cast<int64_t>(abs_amount) / precision());
   if( decimals() )
   {
      auto fract = static_cast<int64_t>(abs_amount) % precision();
      result += "." + fc::to_string(precision() + fract).erase(0,1);
   }
   return sign + result + " " + symbol_name();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the difficult part is to convert the symbol to string which is not shown in your answer. I would appreciate it if you can show how exactly it can be done.

Comment: Do you see the `+ symbol_name()`? That is how you get the symbol

Comment: As Phillip Hamnett says you can get symbol_name! If my answer was useful to you then please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use functions from **./libraries/chain/asset.cpp** directly in your contract. The only available part of EOS API you can use in contacts is located in **./contracts/eosiolib/** folder.
There are files, which define **"asset"** and **"symbol"** structure, but there are no functions, that convert values to string. So, you need to use your implementation inside the contracts.

Here is my implementation I'm using for my smart contracts:

```
std::string asset_to_string(asset val) const
{
    string sign = val.amount < 0 ? "-" : "";
    uint64_t abs_amount = static_cast<uint64_t>(std::abs(val.amount));
    auto precision = val.symbol.precision();

    string result = std::to_string( abs_amount);
    if( precision > 0 )
    {
            auto p = precision;
            uint64_t p10 = 1;
            while(p > 0) {
                    p10 *= 10;
                    p--;
            }

            result = std::to_string( static_cast<uint64_t>(abs_amount / p10));
            auto fract = abs_amount % p10;
            result += "." + std::to_string(p10 + fract).erase(0,1);
    }
    return sign + result + " " + symbol_to_string(val);
}

std::string symbol_to_string(asset val) const
{
    uint64_t v = val.symbol.value;
    v >>= 8;
    string result;
    while (v > 0) {
            char c = static_cast<char>(v & 0xFF);
            result += c;
            v >>= 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've just extracted the code from **./libraries/chain** and used it with **"asset"** and **"symbol"** from **eosiolib**.

Usage:

```
std::string assetString = asset_to_string(assetVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
asset my_asset = asset(10000, S(4, EOS));
std::string myString = my_asset.to_string();
```